# Update records from one table to another in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables:TABLE_PPAL(main table) and a TABLE_TEMP(temporary table)

TABLE_PPAL:

```
    --------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
    ID      | NAME    | LASTNAME     |REF       |DNI          | COUNTRY   | MONTH  | YEAR  | AMOUNT|   
    --------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
    1       |Juan     |Valverde      |23054     |6124123      |           |        |       |       |
    2       |Mark     |Márquez       |42451     |9751434      |           |        |       |       |
    3       |Mary     |Jeans         |19784     |8624244      |           |        |       |       | 
    4       |Phillip  |Butters       |25054     |1251244      |           |        |       |       | 
   ---------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
```

TABLE_TEMP:

```
        --------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+----------+
        ID      | NAME    | LASTNAME     |REF       |DNI          | COUNTRY   | MONTH  | YEAR  | AMOUNT| CURRENCY | 
        --------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+----------+
        1       |Juan     |Valverde      |23054     |6124123      | EEUU      |  APRIL |  2021 | 152.25|   EUR    |
        2       |Juan     |Valverde      |23054     |6124123      | PANAMA    |  JAN   |  2019 | 1700  |   EUR    |
        3       |Mark     |Márquez       |42451     |9751434      | MEXICO    |  MAY   |  2020 | 145.8 |   EUR    |
        4       |Mark     |Márquez       |42451     |9751434      | GERMANY   |  JUN   |  2021 | 1200  |   EUR    |
        5       |Mary     |Jeans         |19784     |8624244      | SPAIN     |  JULY  |  2016 | 1500  |   EUR    |
        6       |Mary     |Jeans         |19784     |8624244      | PORTUGAL  |  JULY  |  2017 | 364.05|   EUR    |
        7       |Mary     |Jeans         |19784     |8624244      | PERU      |  FEB   |  2015 | 45    |   EUR    | 
        8       |Phillip  |Butters       |25054     |1251244      | FRANCE    |  OCTOB |  2018 | 4875  |   EUR    |
        9       |Phillip  |Butters       |25054     |1251244      | BRAZIL    |  DEC   |  2018 | 120.45|   EUR    |
        10      |Phillip  |Butters       |25054     |1251244      | BRAZIL    |  DEC   |  2018 | 120.45|   EUR    |
       ---------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+----------+
```

I want to update the records from my TABLE_TEMP to TABLE_PPAL by checking if "REF" AND "DNI" are the same and have conincidence in both tables. So if they are the same, update the fields ("COUNTRY","MONTH", "YEAR", "AMOUNT") and add lines and if there are duplicates in all fields in the TABLE_TEMP to discard them.

The result would look something like this:
TABLE_PPAL:

```
        --------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
        ID      | NAME    | LASTNAME     |REF       |DNI          | COUNTRY   | MONTH  | YEAR  | AMOUNT|   
        --------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
        1       |Juan     |Valverde      |23054     |6124123      | EEUU      |  APRIL |  2021 | 152.25|
        2       |Juan     |Valverde      |23054     |6124123      | PANAMA    |  JAN   |  2019 | 1700  |
        3       |Mark     |Márquez       |42451     |9751434      | MEXICO    |  MAY   |  2020 | 145.8 |
        4       |Mark     |Márquez       |42451     |9751434      | GERMANY   |  JUN   |  2021 | 1200  |
        5       |Mary     |Jeans         |19784     |8624244      | SPAIN     |  JULY  |  2016 | 1500  |
        6       |Mary     |Jeans         |19784     |8624244      | PORTUGAL  |  JULY  |  2017 | 364.05|
        7       |Mary     |Jeans         |19784     |8624244      | PERU      |  FEB   |  2015 | 45    | 
        8       |Phillip  |Butters       |25054     |1251244      | FRANCE    |  OCTOB |  2018 | 4875  |
        9       |Phillip  |Butters       |25054     |1251244      | BRAZIL    |  DEC   |  2018 | 120.45|
       ---------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
```

the query I use is as follows:

```
UPDATE MY_SCHEMA.TABLE_PPAL, MY_SCHEMA.TABLE_TEMP SET TABLE_PPAL.COUNTRY=TABLE_TEMP.COUNTRY, TABLE_PPAL.MONTH=TABLE_TEMP.MONTH, TABLE_PPAL.YEAR=TABLE_TEMP.YEAR, TABLE_PPAL.AMOUNT=TABLE_TEMP.AMOUNT WHERE TABLE_TEMP.REF=TABLE_PPAL.REF AND TABLE_TEMP.DNI=TABLE_PPAL.DNI;
```

What this query does is that it only updates a single row and not the way I want it to. Can you help me?

Comment: seems to work, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1fbbaa9bde3e255dcfba041274cb8d77

Comment: *by checking if "REF" AND "DNI" are the same and have conincidence in both tables.* This columns pair is not unique in source table. So your updating attempt should be ambiguous, and its final result should be unpredictable. You must find more strict criteria.

Comment: that's exactly what i don't want it to do, i want it to add the other lines as their fields contain different records. the expected result i have left in the publication. @Luuk

Comment: I know it's a bit ambiguous but I can't think of a solution. @Akina

Comment: then try this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e2a26353521f4bbca66dc52af6ba9930

Comment: thank you for your support but I am looking for a solution with 'UPDATE' @Luuk

Comment: With only `UPDATE` you will never get more than 4 records...

Comment: I just updated my table to a more concrete case with my problem, I can't do a "SELECT * " because from my temporary table I'm not going to take all the records that my main table contains. 
I am going to compare the fields ("REF" and "DNI") in both tables, if those fields are the same but the other fields are not ("COUNTRY", "MONTH", "YEAR"...) I add all those rows to my main table updating it. I hope you understand me.

P.S: I don't add the field "CURRENCY" (just to give an example as there are more fields that I don't add to the main table either).

Comment: As @Luuk says, with only `UPDATE`, you can only update the 4 rows in TABLE_PPAL. All others must be inserted.  
**You can't update rows that don't exist!**  
So you must have to do an `UPDATE` AND an `INSERT`, or a `DELETE` AND an `INSERT` (like this ⇒ [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb71a1f91a128ab294d0127bff46585d))

Comment: Ok, I understand it, and... How would it be with a "UPDATE - INSERT"? @Nico207